# Set cookie in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-cookiemanager

I have to set a cookie in a `WebView` in order to authenticate my user.
I've found a lot a code talking about that, but `CookieSyncManager` is deprecated.

And this code seems to not work :

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.setCookie("my_url", "param=value;param=value;param=value");
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: localStorage comes in mind.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your solution ?

Comment: In  [Android L] cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true);  else I think you should set cookie after webView load.

Answer (score 0):

The function `setJavaScriptEnabled` should be called before `setCookie`.

If `webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled` or `webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls` is called after `setCookie`, then `setCookie` will not work.

And maybe you forgot to call `CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mContext).sync()` after set cookie.